# Cannot install a wcf service

Tags: wcf, installation, windows-installer

I created an msi install package but it is failing. The message is "The installer was interrupted before (Name) could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again.

The is the first time I try to install anything on this machine. The machine is Windows Server 2012 R2.

I can install a Windows Form application ok.

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF?  It's an installer issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another forum. You need to go into Service Manager and add the Role Service "IIS6 Management Compatibility".  It is under Web Server - Management Tools.